# In kotlin warning: classpath entry points to a non-existent location: mypath\libs\*

Tags: json, kotlin

`I ran this json kotlin program with

kotlinc -cp Mypath\libs* Main.kt -include-runtime -d Mypath\Main.jar command in command prompt

Kotlin version 1.8.10 (JRE 11.0.11+9-LTS-194) am using windows server 64 bit

using the below program  in Main.kt file

```
Import com.google.gson.Gson
import java.io.File

data class Person(val name: String, val age: Int)

fun main() {
    val gson = Gson()
    val jsonFile = File("data.json")
    val jsonString = jsonFile.readText()
    val person = gson.fromJson(jsonString, Person::class.java)
    println("Name: ${person.name}")
    println("Age: ${person.age}")
}
```

Error:warning: classpath entry points to a non-existent location: mypath\libs*
Main.kt:1:12: error: unresolved reference: google
import com.google.gson.Gson
^
Main.kt:7:16: error: unresolved reference: Gson
val gson = Gson()
^

but my jar files are available in mypath\libs* location

My folder structure :

```
 libs/gson-2.8.6.jar,etc..,
 data.json
 Main.kt
```

`

Comment: Are you using the first import with capital `I` or it's just a typo?

Comment: it's just a typo and am using small i only

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.